# Swift 3.1 Key-Only Dictionary for lookups

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I was wondering weather there is some dictionary or other data types in Swift3.1 that I can use to create tables for lookups only.

For example: 
I want to check if I alredy received a specific String already in O(N).

Of course I could do something like:

```
let dict = ["hello":true, "world":"true"]
```

and then check if my dictionary contains the inputString:

```
dict[input] != nil ? print("got it already") : print("new String")
```

But I would like to get rid of the boolean value that I have to add.

Comment: In O(n) time? An array would do that. Sounds like you're looking for a `Set` though ;)

Comment: alright... I am an idiot :)! Thank you very much!